# displaying date and month only out of a string of date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, date, jsx

I have an array of object with Date on it as a string it looks like this

```
    Object {
      "Date": "2021-01-20T00:00:00",
      "Amount": "2000",
      "Value": 6,
    },
```

then I parse the array of object and display it on the table, however I would like to display the date as
Day/month like  5/1 something like this

Comment: Please share the jsx as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the format of the `Date` string will remain unchanged, some string splitting could do the trick:

```js
const obj = {
  "Date": "2021-01-20T00:00:00",
  "Amount": "2000",
  "Value": 6,
}

const [year, month, day] = obj.Date.substring(0, 10).split('-');

console.log(`${day}/${month}`)
```

Comment: You can avoid substring using `let [year, month, day, ...rest] = obj.Date.split(/\D/)`, and trim leading zeros with `${+day}/${+month}`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get Date object like this

```js
const obj = {
  "Date": "2021-01-20T00:00:00",
  "Amount": "2000",
  "Value": 6,
}

const date = new Date(obj.Date);
const displayDate = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1);
console.log(displayDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
const obj = {
  "Date": "2021-01-20T00:00:00",
  "Amount": "2000",
  "Value": 6,
}
const [_, yyyy, mm, dd] = obj.Date.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/)
console.log(`${dd}/${mm}`)
```